# How to get an element within an element

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping a real state page and trying to get the data of name, location, price, etc... in an excel table. This is the code to get that information:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
for price in soup.find_all('span',{"class":"ann-price"}):
    price_list.append(price.text)
for name in soup.find_all('div',{"itemprop":"name"}):
    name_list.append(name.text)
for meters in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"ann-box-info"}):
    meters_list.append(meters.text)
for rooms in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"ann-box-info"}):
    bedrooms_list.append(rooms.text)
for location in soup.find_all('span',{"class":"ann-info-item"}):
    location_list.append(location.text)
for realtor in soup.find_all('span',{"class":"company-name"}):
    realtor_list.append(realtor.text)
```

Questions:

1. Most offers have the company name as span.company-name inside a div.ann-box-contact. The problem is that whenever a special offer appears without a div.ann-box-contact (thus without company name) instead of leaving the space blank it outputs the name for the next offer, harming the excel's format.
2. Is there any way that I could filtrate those offers by looking for span.company-name **specifically** inside div.ann-box-contact?

Here is the page's code where the company name and the contact box are:

```
<div class="ann-box-contact">
<div class="info">
  <span class="company-photo">
    <span class="user-avatar"></span>
  </span>
  *<span class="company-name">*
    <br>
```

The element within asterisks is the one I want to get but specifically, look for it inside the div.ann-box-contact in order to ignore any offer without Company-name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for; are you trying to find out if `<span class="company-name">` exists or, if it does, to find the actual company name?

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: https://www.encuentra24.com/panama-es/searchresult/all#search=keyword.apartamento|number.50&page=

Comment: there is the URL. What I'm trying is to look for the span class= company-name ONLY inside a contact box in order to ignore all those offers that don't have one and maintain the format of the excel that is returned

Answer (score 1):

You could find the `<div class="ann-box-contact">` first and then search inside to find the `<span class="company-name">` with `beautifulsoup`

Something like this:

```
div = soup.find('div', {'class':'ann-box-contact'})
span = div.find('span',{'class': 'company-name'})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the program outputted an AttributeError:                                              This is the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'                             The error appears in the code:                                             

 for realtor in div.find('span',{"class":"company-name"}):
   realtor_list.append(realtor.text)

Comment: @MikelSanchez What is the exact error? Because I think it's working

Comment: did you check that `div = soup.find('div', {'class':'ann-box-contact'})` found a result?

Comment: And btw you cannot write `for realtor in div.find('span',{"class":"company-name"})`
You have to use `find_all` if you want to iterate over a list

Comment: div = soup.find didn't output any error, I believe the problem comes either from the "for" loop before the div.find or because div can't use the attribute find

Comment: Thanks I knew there was something wrong with the for loop I'll try again

Comment: You are welcome. Can you accept the answer if it's good for you? Thanks :-)

Comment: Still got the same NoneType error with the find_all attribute

Comment: I have to go now sorry. But check the type of  `div` it should be a `bs4.element.tag`
Then check your code indent. To be sure that div is correctly available when you try to access to it with the `find` method :-)